# procedures don't work properly when dealing with files in pascal

Tags: pascal

In this program when I try to put the code blocks [1] and [2] in procedures they don't work properly when  calling them, and when I keep them in the main program only the  first one works properly and the second doesn't and when I comment out the first one the second one works as it's supposed...can you please spot the error, I think it's with getting the files names from the user cause when I choose the file's name it works properly

```
program Linked_lists_files;
type
Node = ^T;
T = record
    num : integer;
    next : Node;
    End;
var
File1 : Text;
N, i, j, cmp, y, x, Num, matrixvalue : integer;
Head, Tail, Head2, Tail2, Head3, Tail3 : Node;
s : string;
matrix : array [1..20, 1..20] of Integer;

//  procedures

// [1]
Procedure fillFile();
Begin
write('Input file name to create : '); 
 readln(s);
 assign(File1,s);
 rewrite(File1);
 Repeat
 write('Enter a number : ');
 readln(N);
 if (N>=0) then
    writeln(File1, N);
 Until (N<0);
 close(File1);
End;

// [2]
Procedure GetFromFile();
Begin
cmp := 0;
 write('Enter file name to read from : '); 
 readln(s);
 assign(File1, s);
 reset(File1);
 while not eof(File1) Do
    Begin
        readln(File1, N);
        if (Head = Nil) then
        Begin
            new(Head);
            Tail := Head;
        End
        Else
        Begin
            new(Tail^.next);
            Tail := Tail^.next;
        End;
        Tail^.num := N;
        Tail^.next := Nil;
        cmp := cmp + 1;
    End;
Close(File1);
Write('Elements of the list : ');
Tail := Head;
if (Head<>nil) then
Begin
    while(Tail <> nil) Do
    Begin
        write('[',Tail^.num,']', ' ');
        Tail := Tail^.next;
    End;
End
Else
Writeln('[!] The list is empty');
writeln;
writeln('Number of elements in the list : ', cmp);
End;

// [3]
Procedure SaveFromFile();
Begin
Head :=  Nil;
write('Enter file name to read from : '); readln(s);
writeln('[+] Fill in your list');
Repeat
write('+ Enter an integer : ');
read(y);
if (y>=0) then
Begin
if (Head = Nil) then
Begin
    new(Head);
    Tail := Head;
End
Else
Begin
    new(Tail^.next);
    Tail := Tail^.next;
End;
Tail^.num := y;
Tail^.next := Nil;
End;
Until y<0;
assign(File1, s);
rewrite(File1);
Tail := Head;
while(Tail <> nil) Do
Begin
    Num := Tail^.num;
    Tail := Tail^.next;
    Writeln(File1, Num);
End;
Close(File1);
Writeln('[+] Elements of the lists have been successfully added to the new file');
End;

// [4]
Procedure SquareMatrix();
Begin
cmp := 0;
x := 0;
writeln('[+] Fill in your list');
Repeat
write('+ Enter an integer : ');
read(y);
if (y>=0) then
Begin
if (Head3 = Nil) then
Begin
    new(Head3);
    Tail3 := Head3;
End
Else
Begin
    new(Tail3^.next);
    Tail3 := Tail3^.next;
End;
Tail3^.num := y;
Tail3^.next := Nil;
cmp := cmp + 1;
End;
Until y<0;

while (cmp<>1) Do
Begin
    if (cmp mod 2 <> 0) and (cmp <> 1) then 
        x := x + 1;
    cmp := cmp div 2;
End;    
if (x>0) then
writeln('[-] False')
Else
writeln('[+]True');
End;

// [5]
Procedure ElementsOfSM();
Begin
cmp := 0;
x := 0;
writeln('[+] Fill in your list');
Repeat
write('+ Enter an integer : ');
read(y);
if (y>=0) then
Begin
if (Head = Nil) then
Begin
    new(Head);
    Tail := Head;
End
Else
Begin
    new(Tail^.next);
    Tail := Tail^.next;
End;
Tail^.num := y;
Tail^.next := Nil;
cmp := cmp + 1;
End;
Until y<0;
Tail := Head;
i := 1;
j := 1;
        while(Tail <> nil) Do
        Begin
            matrixvalue := Tail^.num;
            matrix[i,j] := matrixvalue;
            Tail := Tail^.next;
            j := j + 1;
            if (j = sqrt(cmp)+1) then
                Begin
                    i := i + 1;
                    j := 1;
                End;
            
        End;
for i:=1 to cmp Do
    for j:=1 to cmp Do
    Begin
        if (matrix[i,j]<>0) then
        writeln('[',matrix[i,j],']',' : ','[',i,',',j,']');
    End; 
End;

// [6]
Procedure Element();
Begin
write('Enter the number of the line : ');
read(i);
write('Enter the number of the column : ');
read(j);
write('The element corresponding to ','[',i,',',j,'] is : ','[',matrix[i,j],']');
writeln;
End;

// [7]
Procedure WriteP();
Begin
write('Enter the number of the line : ');
read(i);
write('Enter the number of the column : ');
read(j);
write('Enter the value you want to pass in : ');
read(N);
matrix[i,j] := N;
writeln('The new matrix');  
for i:=1 to cmp Do
    for j:=1 to cmp Do
    Begin
        if (matrix[i,j]<>0) then
        writeln('[',matrix[i,j],']',' : ','[',i,',',j,']');
    End; 
writeln;
End;

// [8]
Procedure Content();
Begin
write('Enter the number of the line : ');
read(i);
write('Enter the number of the column : ');
read(j);
writeln('The value stored inn this cell is : ','[', matrix[i,j],']');
End;

// Start of main program
Begin
 Head := Nil;
 Repeat
 writeln('*********** MENU ***********');
 writeln('[1] fillFile');
 writeln('[2] GetFromFile');
 writeln('[3] SaveFromFile');
 writeln('[4] SquareMatrix');
 writeln('[5] ElementsOfSM');
 writeln('[6] Element');
 writeln('[7] WriteP');
 writeln('[8] Content');
 writeln('*********** End ***********');
 write('Choose one : ');
 read(N);
 
 case N of
 1 : fillFile();
 
 2 : GetFromFile();
 
 3 : SaveFromFile();
 
 4 : SquareMatrix();
 
 5 : ElementsOfSM();
 
 6 : Element();
 
 7 : WriteP();
 
 8 : Content();
 End;
 
 Until (N<>1) and (N<>2) and (N<>3) and (N<>4) and (N<>5) and (N<>6) and (N<>7) and (N<>8) and (N<>9);

End.
```

Comment: When you pass an open text file as a parameter, you have to pass it *by reference*, **not** *by value*, i.e. procedure `DoSomething(var F : Text ...`, not `procedure DoSomething(F : Text...`.

Comment: Hi thanks, but isn't possible to let the user pass in the name of the file that we want to get data from or write to without giving any parameters to the procedure and then calling it?

Comment: because when I do so for the first block of code it directly goes to ask for  entering a number and it doesn't let me enter the name of the text file I want to create

Comment: same thing for the second one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you describe is being caused by the known  behaviour of the `Read` statement;  basically, the second (and subsequent) times you call it, it returns immediately, without waiting for any keyboard input and without reading anything.

This happen because FPC is closely based on Object Pacal in the commercial Delphi development package, and in Delphi's case, this is the officially documented behaviour.

From the Delphi (v7) online help:

> Delphi syntax:
> Text files:
> procedure Read( [ var F: Text; ] V1 [, V2,...,Vn ] );
>
> Description
> The Read procedure can be used in Delphi code in the following ways.
> [...]
> With a type string variable:
>
> Read reads all characters up to, but not including, the next end-of-line
> marker or until Eof(F) becomes true; it does not skip to the next line after reading. If the resulting string is longer than the maximum length of the string variable, it is truncated.
> After the first Read, **each subsequent Read sees the end-of-line marker and returns a zero-length string** (emphasis added).
> Use multiple Readln calls to read successive string values.

Fortunately, the solution is simple, use `readln`, instead of `read`, as in

```
readln(s);
```

**Update** Make sure you replace **all** instances of `read` by `readln`, as you have left a number of them unchanged, as @TomBrunberg has commented.

After that, run your code again and select `1` from the menu and you will find that `fillFile` executes, but the program terminates on the `until ...` line.  And that's because it is a **very** bad idea to use the same global variable, in this case `N` for several different purposes throughout the program.  So, you should edit your code further (and carefully) so that as far as possible it only uses global variables for global purposes.  Turn **all** all the other variables into local variables, preferably with different names than the global ones.  If after that you are still having problems, submit a new question focused on that.

Comment: the problem raised again, when I just compile the first block of code it works well but when I use it as a procedure it does't work, the problem you spotted happens again

Comment: should I provide you with the procedures?

Comment: Which problem **exactly** are you talking about?  Anyway, yes, provide the procedures.

Comment: Yes the problem is the one you talked about but using ReadLn didnt' fix it

Comment: Well, please edit the code in your q to show what you now say doesn't work.

Comment: for example when I call procedure number one, it  doesn't let me enter the file's name, it directly asks for entering an integer, same  thing for the second one..

Comment: @Uranium_x02 You still have plenty of `read()` in code sections 3, 4, 5, 6 ..... You need to change every user entry to be `readln()`. If you have one call for user entry with `read()`, then the CR LF chars from the `Enter` will remain in the input buffer. I just noted that you have a `read()` under the menu. That is the main reason for what happened as you described in your previous comment.

Comment: Thanks@TomBrunberg.  Interestingly, the OP has stumbled into a problem that the D& OLH doesn't document:  after `read(s)`, `readln(s)` also returns immediately without waiting for user input.

Comment: @TomBrunberg thank you so much. Now I understood the problem and got the program working.

Comment: @MartynA Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help and time

Comment: Martyn, the case with a `read()` followed by a `readln()` is not documented separately, but can be deducted from what we already know. User enters a number, say 8 and hits "Enter". Buffer contains 8, CR, LF. `Read()` reads 8 but stops "in front of" CRLF. When readln() is called it sees the CRLF, so there's nothing to wait for. It's as the user had just hit the Enter key. So, `readln()` reads "past the" CRLF, but because there was nothing in front of the CRLF, it has nothing to return (except CRLF). On a subsequent `readln()` the function would wait for user input.